# Is the second argument to mat-color opacity?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

Is the second  argument to `mat-color` opacity?

This is an example:

```
mat-color($warn, 0.15)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According with [angular/components](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/63a8ff568f02db2f9aa1de2a836b065a4785e8f7/src/material/core/theming/_theming.scss#L48) source code. Yes, it will be treated as opacity.

```
@param $color-map The theme palette (output of mat-palette).
@param $hue The hue from the palette to use. If this is a value between 0 and 1, it will
   be treated as opacity.
@param $opacity The alpha channel value for the color.
```

`@function mat-color($palette, $hue: default, $opacity: null)`